# custom helper using assemble-middleware-i18n

Tags: internationalization, handlebars.js, assemble

I was reading the source code of [assemble-middleware-i18n](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-middleware-i18n), and saw something like `<title>{{i18n "title"}}</title>`, how can i18n helper be used if it is not registered through `Handlebars.registerHelper` function ?

Comment: I guess it's the line: params.assemble.engine.registerFunctions(helper.i18n);